# How to make Birthday Reminder in j2me Application

Tags: java-me

I want to create birthday reminder for java devices. So can you please tell me what can be used for remindering birthday when user enters date in my app.??
Please answer..

Answer (score 0):

You will use JSR 75 PIM API. Here is a good article about it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/pim5-155424.html
Check for "Adding a PIM Item".